# Override Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action in Magento

Tags: magento

I've done my best to figure this out, but I can't seem to get the following Controller to override in Magento:

**Mage/Core/Controller/Varian/Action**

Right now I have the following files for my extension:

**app/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php**

**app/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Core/etc/config.xml**

**app/etc/modules/MyCompany_MyModule.xml**

My confusion lies in the config.xml.  I've previously overwritten Controllers found in the **controllers** directory, but not the **Controller**.  I'm not entirely clear on the difference or if the method for overriding files in the Controller directory is different.

Here's what I have in my config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <MyCompany_MyModule>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </MyCompany_MyModule>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <controller>
                <Mage_Core>
                    <rewrite>
                        <front_action>MyCompany_MyModule_Core_Controller_Front_Action</front_action>
                    </rewrite>
                </Mage_Core>
            </controllers>
        </global>
    </config>
```

Can someone please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: What are you wanting to change? There may be another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot accomplish what you want via Magento configured classname rewrites. If you notice, you are changing a superclass (other classes extend from it), and the discovery of the class definition occurs through the autoloading logic from `Varien_Autoload::autoload()`.

If you must change the definition of this class, you can copy the entire file to *app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/* and make your changes there. You will need to merge updates to this class anytime that you upgrade Magento.

Comment: Well that sucks :P

My end objective is to redirect the user on the frontend to another page if a specific cookie value doesn't exist.  Do you think overriding the Action.php class is the correct way of solving this?

Comment: Well I decided to override the Html block located in app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html.php.

Since pretty much every page in Magento loads in the Html block, it's easy to integrate a redirect function in the construction function for that block class.

Comment: You can do this *much* less invasively and in a much more framework-appropriate approach by observing the pre-rendering events. See `controller_action_predispatch` event from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action`.

Comment: Thanks Ben!  I had no idea about the event observers.  I'm using your suggested method instead.  There's a lot to learn with Magento's framework, so I appreciate all the knowledge being passed along :)

Answer (score 0):

I have also once modified Controller functions, but I think I in the end just patched the original Controller instead of overwriting it. I may be wrong, but I think Magento has no support for overwriting Controller classes.

If I recall correctly they are even called statically in the code at some points.

Comment: Correct. There is a mechanism for adding additional module directories under a frontname, but no classname rewriting as there is for block, helpers, models, and resource models.

Answer (score 0):

Since the declaration on the magento controllers

`class Mage_Catalog_ProductController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action`

If was directly extends the class. What I did is replace all the controllers in somehow.

`class Mage_Catalog_ProductController extends MyCompany_Core_Controller_Front_Action`

To replace all controllers, I user this linux command

`find app/code/core/Mage/*/controllers/ -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action/MyCompany_Core_Controller_Front_Action/g'`

Comment: Doesn't this kind of defeat the purpose of not overriding core files?